# JHipster Integration Tests with LocalStack testcontainers

Tags: jhipster, testcontainers, localstack

I have a JHipster (**7.9.3**) application with Kafka and Postgres TestContainers used in the integration tests. I want to integrate my application with S3 storage. For this purpose, I want to write some Integration tests using LocalStack testcontainer.

I have created a new annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EmbeddedS3 {
}
```

and added localstack dependency to the project:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>localstack</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

created a LocalStackTestContainer as:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.testcontainers.containers.localstack.LocalStackContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.output.Slf4jLogConsumer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

public class LocalStackTestContainer implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private LocalStackContainer localStackContainer;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalStackTestContainer.class);

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        if (null != localStackContainer) {
            localStackContainer.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if (null == localStackContainer) {
            localStackContainer =
                new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:1.2.0"))
                    .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3)
                    .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                    .withReuse(true)
            ;
        }
        if (!localStackContainer.isRunning()) {
            localStackContainer.start();
        }
    }

    public LocalStackContainer getLocalStackContainer() {
        return localStackContainer;
    }
}
```

and adjusted TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer method  with:

```java
            EmbeddedS3 s3LocalStackAnnotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(testClass, EmbeddedS3.class);
            if (null != s3LocalStackAnnotation) {
                log.debug("detected the EmbeddedS3 annotation on class {}", testClass.getName());
                log.info("Warming up the localstack S3");

                if (null == localStackTestContainer) {
                    localStackTestContainer = beanFactory.createBean(LocalStackTestContainer.class);
                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(LocalStackTestContainer.class.getName(), localStackTestContainer);
//                    ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).registerDisposableBean(LocalStackTestContainer.class.getName(), localStackTestContainer);
                }
            }
```

Added @EmbeddedS3 annotation to the @IntegrationTest annotation as:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AgentMarlinApp.class, AsyncSyncConfiguration.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class, TestLocalStackConfiguration.class})
@EmbeddedKafka
@EmbeddedSQL
@EmbeddedS3
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles({"testdev", "it-test"})
public @interface IntegrationTest {
    // 5s is the spring default https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/29185a3d28fa5e9c1b4821ffe519ef6f56b51962/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/DefaultWebTestClient.java#L106
    String DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = "PT5S";

    String DEFAULT_ENTITY_TIMEOUT = "PT5S";
}
```

To initialize AmazonS3 client I have @TestConfiguration:

```java
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3(LocalStackTestContainer localStackTestContainer) {
        LocalStackContainer localStack = localStackTestContainer.getLocalStackContainer();
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                    localStack.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3).toString(),
                    localStack.getRegion()
                )
            )
            .withCredentials(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(localStack.getAccessKey(), localStack.getSecretKey())
                )
            )
            .build();
    }
```

I have 2 integration classes (ending with *IT), when first class tests are executed I see that testcontainers are started

```
2022-10-30 14:34:42.031 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Starting container: testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3
2022-10-30 14:34:42.032 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Trying to start container: testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3 (attempt 1/1)
2022-10-30 14:34:42.033 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Starting container: testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3
2022-10-30 14:34:42.033  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3
2022-10-30 14:34:42.371  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3 is starting: 5505472cec1608db3383ebeeee99a8d02b48331a53f5d53613a0a53c1cd51986
2022-10-30 14:34:43.271  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3]           : Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3 started in PT1.2706326S
2022-10-30 14:34:43.282  INFO 27208 --- [           main] o.t.utility.RyukResourceReaper           : Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
2022-10-30 14:34:43.283  INFO 27208 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Checking the system...
2022-10-30 14:34:43.283  INFO 27208 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2022-10-30 14:34:43.284  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL environment variable set to localhost (to match host-routable address for container)
2022-10-30 14:34:43.284 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Starting container: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
2022-10-30 14:34:43.285 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Trying to start container: localstack/localstack:1.2.0 (attempt 1/1)
2022-10-30 14:34:43.285 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Starting container: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
2022-10-30 14:34:43.285  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Creating container for image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
2022-10-30 14:34:44.356  WARN 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Reuse was requested but the environment does not support the reuse of containers
To enable reuse of containers, you must set 'testcontainers.reuse.enable=true' in a file located at C:\Users\artjo\.testcontainers.properties
2022-10-30 14:34:44.581  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Container localstack/localstack:1.2.0 is starting: d09c4e105058444699a29338b85d7294efec29941857e581daf634d391395869
2022-10-30 14:34:48.321  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [localstack/localstack:1.2.0]         : Container localstack/localstack:1.2.0 started in PT5.0370436S
2022-10-30 14:34:48.321  INFO 27208 --- [           main] ContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory : Warming up the sql database
2022-10-30 14:34:48.327 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Starting container: postgres:14.5
2022-10-30 14:34:48.327 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Trying to start container: postgres:14.5 (attempt 1/1)
2022-10-30 14:34:48.327 DEBUG 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Starting container: postgres:14.5
2022-10-30 14:34:48.327  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Creating container for image: postgres:14.5
2022-10-30 14:34:48.328  WARN 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Reuse was requested but the environment does not support the reuse of containers
To enable reuse of containers, you must set 'testcontainers.reuse.enable=true' in a file located at C:\Users\artjo\.testcontainers.properties
2022-10-30 14:34:48.415  INFO 27208 --- [           main]  [postgres:14.5]                       : Container postgres:14.5 is starting: 5e4fcf583b44345651aad9d5f939bc913d62eafe16a73017379c9e43f2028ff4
```

But when the second IT test is started the LocalStackTestContainer bean is not available anymore.

How do I need to configure this so localstack container bean remain available during all the tests execution?

######################## UPDATE 01.11.2022 ########################

Other testcontainers are configured the same way (no changes from the auto generated code)

```java
public class TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.class);

    private static LocalStackTestContainer localStackTestContainer;
    private static KafkaTestContainer kafkaBean;
    private static SqlTestContainer devTestContainer;
    private static SqlTestContainer prodTestContainer;

    @Override
    public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(Class<?> testClass, List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
        return (context, mergedConfig) -> {
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
            TestPropertyValues testValues = TestPropertyValues.empty();

//            EmbeddedS3 s3LocalStackAnnotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(testClass, EmbeddedS3.class);
//            if (null != s3LocalStackAnnotation) {
//                log.debug("detected the EmbeddedS3 annotation on class {}", testClass.getName());
//                log.info("Warming up the localstack S3");
//
//                if (null == localStackTestContainer) {
//                    localStackTestContainer = beanFactory.createBean(LocalStackTestContainer.class);
//                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(LocalStackTestContainer.class.getName(), localStackTestContainer);
////                    ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).registerDisposableBean(LocalStackTestContainer.class.getName(), localStackTestContainer);
//                }
//            }
            EmbeddedSQL sqlAnnotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(testClass, EmbeddedSQL.class);
            if (null != sqlAnnotation) {
                log.debug("detected the EmbeddedSQL annotation on class {}", testClass.getName());
                log.info("Warming up the sql database");
                if (
                    Arrays
                        .asList(context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles())
                        .contains("test" + JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
                ) {
                    if (null == devTestContainer) {
                        try {
                            Class<? extends SqlTestContainer> containerClass = (Class<? extends SqlTestContainer>) Class.forName(
                                this.getClass().getPackageName() + ".PostgreSqlTestContainer"
                            );
                            devTestContainer = beanFactory.createBean(containerClass);
                            beanFactory.registerSingleton(containerClass.getName(), devTestContainer);
                            // ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).registerDisposableBean(containerClass.getName(), devTestContainer);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    testValues =
                        testValues.and(
                            "spring.r2dbc.url=" + devTestContainer.getTestContainer().getJdbcUrl().replace("jdbc", "r2dbc") + ""
                        );
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.r2dbc.username=" + devTestContainer.getTestContainer().getUsername());
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.r2dbc.password=" + devTestContainer.getTestContainer().getPassword());
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.liquibase.url=" + devTestContainer.getTestContainer().getJdbcUrl() + "");
                }
                if (
                    Arrays
                        .asList(context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles())
                        .contains("test" + JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)
                ) {
                    if (null == prodTestContainer) {
                        try {
                            Class<? extends SqlTestContainer> containerClass = (Class<? extends SqlTestContainer>) Class.forName(
                                this.getClass().getPackageName() + ".PostgreSqlTestContainer"
                            );
                            prodTestContainer = beanFactory.createBean(containerClass);
                            beanFactory.registerSingleton(containerClass.getName(), prodTestContainer);
                            // ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).registerDisposableBean(containerClass.getName(), prodTestContainer);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    testValues =
                        testValues.and(
                            "spring.r2dbc.url=" + prodTestContainer.getTestContainer().getJdbcUrl().replace("jdbc", "r2dbc") + ""
                        );
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.r2dbc.username=" + prodTestContainer.getTestContainer().getUsername());
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.r2dbc.password=" + prodTestContainer.getTestContainer().getPassword());
                    testValues = testValues.and("spring.liquibase.url=" + prodTestContainer.getTestContainer().getJdbcUrl() + "");
                }
            }
            EmbeddedKafka kafkaAnnotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(testClass, EmbeddedKafka.class);
            if (null != kafkaAnnotation) {
                log.debug("detected the EmbeddedKafka annotation on class {}", testClass.getName());
                log.info("Warming up the kafka broker");
                if (null == kafkaBean) {
                    kafkaBean = beanFactory.createBean(KafkaTestContainer.class);
                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(KafkaTestContainer.class.getName(), kafkaBean);
                    // ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).registerDisposableBean(KafkaTestContainer.class.getName(), kafkaBean);
                }
                testValues =
                    testValues.and(
                        "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=" +
                            kafkaBean.getKafkaContainer().getHost() +
                            ':' +
                            kafkaBean.getKafkaContainer().getMappedPort(KafkaContainer.KAFKA_PORT)
                    );
            }
            testValues.applyTo(context);
        };
    }
}
```

######################## UPDATE 02.11.2022 ########################
Reproducible example project can be found here [GITHUB](https://github.com/artyomsv/stackoverflow-question-examples/tree/master/localstack)

Comment: how do you setup kafka and postgres? are you following the same approach for the three of them?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez I have updates the question, but yes, localstack testcontainer was configured same way as kafka and postgres

Comment: please share a minimal sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Does JHipster recommend integrating Testcontainers using beans? I'd say this is not the usual and idiomatic way to integrate with Spring tests.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez, I have added a link to the github repo where you can reproduce this error by execution all tests. For me the first IT test run successfully, but another fails

Comment: @KevinWittek, yes, their code is provided in a way that you register beans for testcontainers. Just wanted to follow the same approach with other containers.